# Use application page as edit form on list?

Tags: event-receivers, form, application-pages, edit-form

I createad an application page and put it under /_layouts/, in the list definition I specified the edit form like so:

```
<FormUrls xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3/contenttype/forms/url">
   <Edit>/_layouts/myform.aspx</Edit>
</FormUrls>
```

This updated the edit form to my application page when I had set `Deployment Conflict Resolution: Auto` on my list which deleted the list and recreated it.

I now have data in the same list in a different farm and I have to set Deployment Conflict Resolution to None. When I deployed this to the other farm the list kept is default edit form and I figured I have to change the form pro grammatically.

I created a feature with a feature receiver and added some code:

```
public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
{
    SPSite site = (SPSite)properties.Feature.Parent;
    var rootWeb = site.RootWeb;
    var myList = Utility.GetRootListByName("myList");
    myList.DefaultEditFormUrl = "/_layouts/myform.aspx";
    taskList.Update();
}
```

However with this code I get `Activate Features': Unable to find an SPForm matching URL /_layouts/myform.aspx`

Should I be able to use an application page as edit form? I mean it works fine when I deploy the list definition for the first time.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://community.bamboosolutions.com/blogs/sharepoint-2010/archive/2011/05/12/sharepoint-2010-cookbook-how-to-create-a-customized-list-edit-form-for-development-in-visual-studio-2010.aspx

http://lsharepoint.com/2012/04/29/adding-gridview-to-sharepoint-2010-list-forms/

Creating Custom List Edit from Different ways check it..